# Are there any production quality JSF 2 implementations yet?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

Are there any production quality JSF 2 implementations yet? If so what are they?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There have always been two major JSF implementations: [Sun Mojarra](http://javaserverfaces.dev.java.net) (the reference implementation) and [Apache MyFaces](http://myfaces.apache.org). Mojarra 2.0 is already been final for months (since [Oct 19, 2009](http://blogs.oracle.com/rlubke/entry/mojarra_2_0_0_is)). The MyFaces JSF 2.0 implementation is still on its way (is still Beta). No other JSF 2.0 implementations comes to mind.

**Update:** as of yesterday (Apr 21, 2010), MyFaces 2.0.0 finally became final.

Answer (score 1):

You might be asking about JSF 2 extended component suites.  Primefaces released a production ready release first, I believe in February 2010.  RichFaces (JBoss/Redhat) just announce a JSF 2 compatible release this week (April 2010).  Icefaces is expected to release theirs in June 2010.

I've successfully used Primefaces in a JSF 2 application - worked great.